# Where is connect() and disconnect() implemented?

Tags: java, android, http

In `java.net.URLConnetion.java` and `java.net.HttpURLConnection.java`, there are only abstract methods for `connect()` and `disconnect()`, respectively.

```
@ abstract public void connect() throws IOException;
@ public abstract void disconnect();
```

Does anyone know where is the actual codes that implement them?

I want to know how the `HttpURLConnection` communicate with TCP stack.

Besides, there are more abstract functions, such as `usingProxy()`. Where is the code for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.net.HttpURLConnection.java` has an implementation `HttpsURLConnectionImpl` that has implemented the method. It uses a delegate `DelegateHttpsURLConnection` that extends `AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection` which has implemented the `connect()` method

Most IDE's you can track all the classes, objects and methods, and download the source files. Fx. `IntelliJ` can do this for you.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your answer!
Is it done automatically?
I just need to call

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.connect()

to connect to a server.
How come there is no explicit calling of 
HttpsURLConnectionImpl 
DelegateHttpsURLConnection
AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection
?
@ by the way, why all of the classes you wrote contain http's'?

Comment: I think i have a plugin to automatically decompile source files (Java Bytecode Decompiler) that automatically decompiles source files. `IntelliJ` will normally ask you to download the original source file if its available.

Comment: I just took a random implementation of `HttpURLConnection` there is multiple of these around.

Comment: Do you know, which implementation of HttpURLConnection is used for Android?

Comment: Sadly i don't. i found this link though: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html, maybe this could help further investigation

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I've looked through that but I couldn't find my answer. :(