# Android URLConnection.setRequestProperty() in android studio doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, java-8

I looked at the source code for `URLConnection.setRequestProperty()` in android studio, and it doesn't seem like it sets anything:

```
public void setRequestProperty(String field, String newValue) {
        checkNotConnected();
        if (field == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("field == null");
        }
    }
```

and here is checkNotConnected():

```
private void checkNotConnected() {
        if (connected) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here? `HttpURLConnection` "the extending class" has no implementation of `setRequestProperty()`, so it seems like this method does absolutely nothing.

Comment: It prevents of setting property after connection and checks the field to ensure it's not null, right?

Comment: Yes, but if the connection hasn't been made, and the field is not null, it should set the request property, right? Where is the code that sets the request property?

Comment: You're right, even if you look carefully the connect method is abstract too with nobody, the implementation is in a compiled jar file

Comment: Just click on the "overriden icon with arrow" next to the method declaration and choose your desired implementation too review

Comment: I don't get it. I see the "overriden icon with arrow," but what do those classes mean as far using android's implementation of HttpURLConnection? I have a HttpURLConnection object - httpURLConnection. What does it matter what other subclasses of URLConnection override setRequestProperty(). If I call httpURLConection.setRequestProperty(), shouldn't it check that class for an implementation, and then if not not that class than its superclasses? Why would it use an implementation from a "sibling" class?

Comment: I got what you are asking, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168030/which-implementation-of-httpurlconnection-is-used-for-android

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154572/where-is-connect-and-disconnect-implemented

Comment: Thanks for the links @NaN, but I think they still leave me wanting for a more conclusive answer. When I ctrl click a class or method in android studio, doesn't that bring me to the class or method that's being implemented at runtime? If not, what am I looking at when I ctrl click a class or a method?

Answer (score 0):

[URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) is an abstract base class that does not implement any specific protocols.

You're looking for [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). This implementation of the `URLConnection` class overrides and functionally implements the `setRequestProperty()` method for use with the HTTP protocol.

UPDATE

After closer inspection I found that `HttpURLConnection` is also an abstract class. It is possible in Android Studio to find any implementations by right clicking the class declaration and clicking Go To -> Implementation(s).

I doubt however that the actual concrete implementation is shipped with the SDK that we work with. I only found Java specific implementations (rt.jar).

This might mean that the actual implementation of `setRequestProperty()` is not included in the SDK.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/JarURLConnection.html also extends URLConnection but probably deals with request properties differently, hence the abstract class.

Comment: Actually if you check the implemention of HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty, the arguments never been used in the body of method and no super is called, If I mistake not khakis is asking for where the property set.

Comment: Exactly, @NaN. To my understanding of java, if a method is not implemented in a child class, the method that is used at runtime is the implementation that is in the closest relative superclass; and being that the hierarchy goes HttpURLConnection --> URLConnection --> Object, it seems it would be the implementation of setRequestProperty() in URLConnection that is called.

Comment: Why would the concrete implementation not be shipped with the SDK that we work with? As developers, shouldn't we know how the tools we're using work?